# Xmpp MUC feature not implemented

Tags: javascript, windows, openfire, strophe

I try to achieve the 'Group Chat' Feature

This is my deployment environment

```
Openfire (3.9.1)
Strophe.js (1.1.3)
strophe.muc.js (1.7.1)
XAMPP for Windows (1.8.2)
```

I send the request want to get xmpp namespace constants

```
<body rid='641581465' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='189f4df8'>
      <iq xmlns='jabber:client' type='get' from='message@tkb-c0695c83280/189f4df8' to='tkb-c0695c83280' id='189f4df8'>
           <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/>
      </iq>
```

after get it response

```
<body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">
<iq id="189f4df8" xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" from="tkb-c0695c83280" to="message@tkb-c0695c83280/189f4df8">
    <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info">
        <identity category="server" name="Openfire Server" type="im"></identity>
        <identity category="pubsub" type="pep"></identity>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#manage-subscriptions"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#modify-affiliations"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retrieve-default"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#collections"></feature>
        <feature var="jabber:iq:private"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"></feature>
        <feature var="vcard-temp"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#publish"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#subscribe"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retract-items"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/offline"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#meta-data"></feature>
        <feature var="jabber:iq:register"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retrieve-subscriptions"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#default_access_model_open"></feature>
        <feature var="jabber:iq:roster"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#config-node"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/address"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#publisher-affiliation"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#item-ids"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#instant-nodes"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/commands"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#multi-subscribe"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#outcast-affiliation"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#get-pending"></feature>
        <feature var="jabber:iq:privacy"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#subscription-options"></feature>
        <feature var="jabber:iq:last"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#create-and-configure"></feature>
        <feature var="urn:xmpp:ping"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retrieve-items"></feature>
        <feature var="jabber:iq:time"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#create-nodes"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#persistent-items"></feature>
        <feature var="jabber:iq:version"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#presence-notifications"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retrieve-affiliations"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#delete-nodes"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#purge-nodes"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"></feature>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm"></feature>
    </query>
</iq>
```

I don't see about ***http://jabber.org/protocol/muc*** namespace constants :(

Soon after , I try to use the ***strophe.muc.js***  and it fucntion ***createInstantRoom*** to send the request

```
<body rid='641581477' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='189f4df8'>
      <iq to='tkb-c0695c83280' type='set' xmlns='jabber:client' id='1:sendIQ'>
                <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner'><x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='submit'/></query>
      </iq>
```

and it response

```
<body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">
      <iq id="1:sendIQ" xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" from="tkb-c0695c83280" to="message@tkb-c0695c83280/189f4df8">
                <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner">
                          <x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit"></x>
                </query>
                <error code="501" type="cancel">
                          <feature-not-implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"></feature-not-implemented>
                </error>
      </iq>
```

I do not know what the wrong places or missing , Please give me some feedback

Answer (score 0):

Try just joining the room instead of the instant create and see what happens. It should create the room if it doesn't exist and the server is set to allow it.

```
conn.muc.join(room, nick, msg_handler_cb, pres_handler_cb, roster_cb, password, history_attrs)
```